# Linked List , Data structures , Structure

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

What is the exact difference between 
       struct node head 
and 
         struct node *head 
if my structure is of following form -

```
struct node 
{int data;
struct node *next;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

One is a struct *instance* (`struct node head`) and the other is a *pointer* to a struct instance (`struct node * head`).

```c
struct node a; /* Allocate space for a new node struct "a". */
a.data = 123;
a.next = NULL;

struct node * b = &a; /* Create a pointer "b" referring to "a". */
b->data = 234;
// Now a.data == 234.
```

Comment: what if I don't  assign &a to b ?

Comment: @GauravVishwakarma: if you don't assign &a to b then it is [a "dangling pointer"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) (one that is not guaranteed to point to anything valid or useful); dereferencing the pointer may crash the program.

Answer (score 0):

struct node head --> "head" is a variable of type "struct node" i.e. sizeof of head= sizeof(struct node)

struct node *head --> "head" is a pointer to structure of type "struct node", hence sizeof head= general pointer size.

you can do,
head.data=x;
head.next=NULL;

but you cannot do
head->data=x;
head->next=NULL;

since when you say "struct node head", the memory is already allocated for you unlike the later case where you need to do dynamic memory allocation before using those memory.